# DRF ListAPIView return manytomany value names instead of pk

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a Post Model contains tags field that have ManyToManyField to categories Model,

when i call REST ListAPIView all post tags returns in pk
I have tried to override list function in ListAPIView and map all tags_names for every post
but this takes a huge time and destroys the performance

I hope/Believe there something built in for this case

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    content = RichTextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Categories(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('tag_name',)
        unique_together = ('tag_name',)
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Post
from .serializers import NewPostSerializer, PostSerializer


class NewPost(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = NewPostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser]


class PostList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class NewPostSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'tags']

        read_only_fields = ['tags', 'author_id']
```

when i visit ListApiView link returned results would be like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 30,
        "title": "post title test",
        "content": "lorem text",
        "author": 3,
        "tags": [
            8, # should be games
            3  # should be action
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To optimize performance you should use `prefetch_related`. This reduces the number of queries to your database to only 1 request to fetch all the related tags for all of your posts.

```py
class PostList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.prefetch_related('tags').all()
    serializer_class = NewPostSerializer
```

Now for the serialization of your tags you have to create a new serializer.

```py
class TagSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Categories
        fields = ['name']
```

You can then use this serializer in your `NewPostSerializer`.

```py
class NewPostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'tags']

        read_only_fields = ['author_id']
```

The results of this should be `"tags": [{"name": "ABC"},{"name": "EFG"}]`.

Comment: not working same results i did added a TagSerializer and deleted my migrations and also the DB nothing have been changed same pk results

Comment: Well your are doing something else wrong. I found a similar question here, and the answer is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925690/django-how-to-serialize-from-manytomanyfield-and-list-all

Comment: And another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182092/django-rest-framework-serializing-many-to-many-field

Comment: Oh you have to use NewPostSerializer of course... I edited my answer, as you were using PostSerializer on your view but you gave us NewPostSerializer code in your question.

Comment: you are right i edited tags field in PostSerializer and its working now thank u 
edit your answer to select it as solved

Comment: The code above works, I just used the name of the serializer you actually provided in your question, I have no idea what your PostSerializer looks like and I don't think it matters....

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **SlugRelatedField**, This will return a list of names instead of list of pks

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class NewPostSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='tag_name'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'tags']

        read_only_fields = ['author_id']
```